# Capybara Ambiguous match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason when I do this:

```
click_on("Save")
```

My Capybara detects both:

```
<button>Save</button>
<button>Save & Schedule</button>
```

And so it gives "ambiguous match: 2 elements found" error.

Is there a way to tell it to do exact match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You have to add uniq ids for these buttons since capybara 2.0 rises an error if more than one element was found.